# Is there any way to implement Disaster Recovery on Minio?

Tags: backup, minio, disaster-recovery, backup-strategies

we are trying to implement "disaster recovery" on Minio. Are there any documentations about how to implement DRC on Minio? Has anyone done it? Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout the documentation here https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/administration/bucket-replication.html#minio-replication-behavior-resync

Comment: Also https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/reference/minio-mc/mc-mirror.html is useful.